# TextureAtlas - how does it affect on RAM usage in open world game?

Tags: libgdx, game-development, texture-atlas

I plan to use TextureAtlas in my open world 2d game.

I need to load textures dynamically (because there are thousands of them, so I cannot load all at once). I plan to load textures that are needed at specific moment in gameplay. Also for some reasons I cannot have many texture atlases per map location.

Generally, I must avoid situation that I read all textures (entire atlas), because RAM usage will be too large. How the TextureAtlas work? Is is possible to keep the atlas open during entire game, but read from the atlas (to the RAM) only chosen textures when needed without worrying about RAM usage?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load portions of a TextureAtlas. It is all or nothing. You will have to use multiple atlases and carefully plan what to put in each atlas such that you don’t have to load all of them simultaneously.

A Texture represents a single image loaded into GPU memory for use in OpenGL. A page of a TextureAtlas corresponds to a single Texture. Typically, you will have multiple TextureRegions on each page (Texture) of a TextureRegion. If you don’t, there’s no point in using TextureAtlas. The point of TextureAtlas is to avoid SpriteBatch having to flush vertex data and swap OpenGL textures for every sprite you draw. If you draw consecutive TextureRegions from the same Texture (or atlas page), they are batched together into a single mesh and OpenGL texture so it performs better.

Libgdx doesn’t support loading individual pages of a TextureAtlas though. That would make it too complicated to use. So, if you are doing a lot of loading and unloading, I recommend avoiding multipage atlases. Use AssetManager to very easily load and unload what you need.

Comment: Btw. I saw another issue. Loading assets using new Texture or even with AssetManager requires to be done in thread with OpenGL context... It means that it's not possible to dynamically load textures without blocking entire render method in game and also it's impossible to load textures using many threads, so it will be too slow.

Comment: Is any way to achieve non-blocking texture loading (with no loading screen) using AssetManager?

Comment: The bitmap can be loaded to RAM on a background thread. Then it can be transferred to the GPU RAM only on the rendering thread, but that’s the quicker part. It’s the same challenge every open world game has on any game engine. AssetManager automatically does it this way for you if you incrementally update it in your render loop instead of using `finishLoading()`. You can find instructions if you look up how to do an animated loading screen with libgdx assetmanager. You’ll want to start loading the appropriate atlas when your player approaches but hasn’t quite reached the next area.

Comment: When it is incrementally loading, it will not load more than one Texture per render thread frame. So each time you call `update` in your render loop, it checks if any textures have been loaded to RAM on a background thread and are ready to load to GPU RAM. If there are any ready, it will only do at most one of them per `update()` call. When your player reaches the new area such that you have to have all textures ready for that area, then you’re forced to call `finishLoading()` if it hasn’t finished in time and you’ll have a freeze of your game. You might have noticed this occasionally

Comment: happening even in AAA console open world games, especially when you’re traveling faster than the usual means. But you can try to prevent it by predicting which next area the player is traveling toward early enough that it’s textures can be loaded in time.

Comment: I have this prediction already done by loading not only current area but also neighbouring areas. I tried solution with update() method and it works now.
My mistake was that I also created Pixmap after loading new texture (I need pixmap for my game editor for other purposes) and it causes awful lags. 
Back to the point: Solution with AssertManager works, at least for fast CPU with fast SSD disc.

Comment: As I understand:
load method from AssetManager together with update method will load texture to RAM, but it will be moved to VRAM only in a thread with OpenGL context after using update (or get(...)) method from AssetManager.

Is it correct or maybe get method does nothing that getting already loaded texture from VRAM?

And generally, based on this whole info: if I want to speed up moving data from RAM to VRAM I cannot do it using more than 1 thread, so I am forced to use only 1 thread for that, but I can speed up loading from disc using load and update method.

Comment: That’s mostly right, but `update` is responsible for both. If you call `update` in your render loop, eventually it will synchronously do the VRAM transfer and finish loading that asset on the render thread. Calling `get` I think enforces immediate finishing loading of that asset, but the hope is that `update` has already achieved that by the time you need `get`. If update has already finished multiple assets you may need when the player reaches a new area, then you won’t have multiple `get` calls in the same frame causing multiple VRAM texture loads on the render thread on the same frame.